# Calculate significance level and power for exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution

My textbook is unclear about how to do this with exponential distributions (it spends the whole time talking about normal ones), so I'm asking this here to see if I got it right.

The question mentions a statistical test such that:

$H_{0} : \lambda = 2$

$H_{1} : \lambda > 2$

$H_{0}$ is rejected if $X > 3$

(There's only one data point).

**a) Calculate the significance level.**

Assuming $H_{o}$ is true, we have that $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 2$ and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$.

$$P(X > 3\mid H_0) = 1 \ - P(X \leq 3)$$

$$1 - e^{-\lambda (3)} = 1 - e^{-1.5} = 0.77686983985$$

**b) Calculate the power level when $\lambda = 2.5$**

\begin{align}
& P(X > 0.7769\mid\lambda = 2.5) \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 - e^{-\lambda(0.7769)} = 1 - e^{-2.5(0.7769)} = 0.8566
\end{align}

**c) If the actual value of $\lambda$ is $2.5$, is this procedure going to make a good decision?**

Yes, because the power is high?

**Why I think I'm missing something:** I haven't used the info $H_1 : \lambda > 2$ given in the question

EDIT: I don't know why I said $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 2$. I was thinking about something else. Here's the alternative answer:

Significance level

\begin{align}
& P(X > 3\mid H_0) = 1 - P(X \leq 3) \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 - e^{-3(2)} = 0.9975
\end{align}

Power

$$P(X > 0.9975\mid\lambda = 2.5)$$

$$1 - e^{-2.5(0.9975)} = 0.9174$$

Comment: Is $2$ the rate or the mean? You say "$H_{0} : \lambda = 2$" but later say "Assuming $H_{o}$ is true, we have that $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 2$ and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$"

Comment: @Henry , my mistake, I was thinking about something else. I added an alternative answer

Comment: You wrote $P(X > 3\mid H_0) = 1 - P(X \leq 3) = 1 - e^{-3(2)}.$ That is wrong. If the density is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge0,$ then $\Pr(X>3\mid H_0) = \Pr(X\ge 3) = e^{-\lambda\cdot3}. \qquad$

Comment: If $\lambda$ is the rate, then it doesn't make sense to reject $\lambda=2$ in favor of an alternative that $\lambda>2$ when $X$ is large. If $\lambda$ is the mean, then that would make sense. Hence I am suspicious of this whole thing.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and I should add that if $\lambda$ is the mean rather than the rate, then you have $\Pr(X\ge 3) = e^{-3/\lambda}. \qquad$

Comment: The question mentions the exponential distribution pdf $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. The mean, If I understood the textbook correctly, is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated the problem makes no sense, and not surprisingly, you have made
some mistakes in dealing with exponential probabilities. I will do my best
to write something helpful.

Suppose $H_0: \mu = 2$ and $H_a: \mu > 2.$ Then it makes sense to reject
if $X > 3.$

> Because large values of $X$ would be associated with large parameter $\mu$ and small values of rate $\lambda = 1/\mu,$ it would make no sense to
>   reject for large $X$ if the null and and alternative hypotheses were
>    $H_0: \lambda = 2$ and $H_a: \lambda > 2.$

Then the significance level is 
$$P(\text{Rej}\,|\,\mu = 2) = P(X > 3\,|\,\mu = 2) = e^{-\lambda(3)} = 
e^{-1.5} = 0.2231.$$

In R statistical software, the exponential functions use the rate $\lambda = 1/\mu$ as parameter and `pexp` is an exponential CDF. So the computation in R is:

```
 1 - pexp(3, rate=1/2)
 [1] 0.2231302
 exp(-1.5)
 [1] 0.2231302
```

The power against the alternative that $\mu = 2.5$ is
$$P(\text{Rej}\,|\,\mu = 2.5) = P(X > 3\,|\, \mu= 2.5)
= e^{-\lambda(3)} = e^{-(1/2.5)(3)} = e^{-1.2} = 0.3012.$$

```
 1 - pexp(3, rate=0.4)
[1] 0.3011942
exp(-1.2)
[1] 0.3011942
```

The figure below shows the null distribution with $\mu = 2,\,$ $(\lambda = 0.5)$ (in blue)
and the particular alternative distribution with $\mu = 2.5,\,$ $(\lambda = 0.4)$
(in red). The rejection region is the interval $(3, \infty).$ Rejection 
probabilities are areas under the curves to the right of the vertical dotted
line. The probability of rejection is a little higher under the alternative. This is a difficult testing situation because there is so little difference
between the null and alternative distributions.

[image]

---

*Note:* Tests based on only one observation are seldom of practical use.
Instead, suppose $n = 100,\,$ $H_0: \mu = 2,\,$ $H_a: \mu > 2.$ Then it makes sense
to reject $H_0$ when $\bar X > 2.34,$ which gives significance level about
$\alpha = 0.05.$

Using moment generating functions, one can show that 
$\bar X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(shape = 100, scale = n\lambda),$ where $\lambda = 1/\mu.$ Then $E(\bar X) = \mu$ and $SD(\bar X) = \mu/\sqrt{n} = \mu/10.$

The significance level is 5% and the power against the alternative $\mu = 2.5,\,
\lambda = 0.4$ is about 73%.

```
1 - pgamma(2.34, 100, 100*.5)
[1] 0.04997338
1 - pgamma(2.34, 100, 100*.4)
[1] 0.7325898
```

A plot of density curves of the distribution of $\bar X$ for $\mu = .5$ (null hypothesis) and $\mu = .4$ (specific alternative) are much different, so that
a practical test is possible.

[image]