# Hypothesis Testing $X \sim Exp(\text{mean} =\frac{1}{\theta})$: Rejection Region and Power Function

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am working on a problem and I would like to have some advice.  The following is the given information.

1), $X$ is exponential with mean $\frac{1}{\theta}$.

2), $H_0: \theta =5$ vs $H_1: \theta<5$

3), $\alpha=.05$

and our goal is

a), Find the rejection region.

b), Find the power function and determine where it is maximized.

What I have tried so far is this.

Edited:

$$
Pr[X > k | \theta = 5] = \alpha$$
so

$$e^{-k(5)} = \alpha$$
and 
$$\begin{align}
k & = -\frac{1}{5}\ln (\alpha) \\
& \sim .599
\end{align}$$

So I am thinking that the rejection region is when the sample is greater than or equal to $.599 \space$ .

Moving on,

$$\begin{align}
\gamma(\theta) & = Pr[X > .599|\theta < 5] \\
& = e^{-.599 \space \theta}
\end{align}$$

I am more used to using concrete numbers rather than theory, so I am not too confident if I am doing this right.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The function $\gamma(\theta)=1-e^{-0.0103\theta}$ is monotonically increasing in $\theta$. And $\gamma(0)=0$, in particular. So the closer $\theta$ to 5, the larger power function is. It is meaningless and indicates that the rejection region is selected incorrectly:  the great difference of hypothesis should provide large value of pover function, and not vice versa.
Note that expected value of $X$ is reciprocal to $\theta$. So the smaller $\theta$, the greater should be $X$. So good rejection region should be $X>k$. For this case $\sup \gamma(\theta) = \gamma(0)$ although $\theta>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Does it look better now?

Comment: Yes, I like it better

Comment: Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866547/calculate-significance-level-and-power-for-exponential-distribution/2866631#2866631) or look at Wikipedia on exponential distribution.